# What is the analytic continuation of $\varphi(s)=\sum_{n \ge 1} e^{-n^s}?$

Tags: cv.complex-variables, riemann-zeta-function, schwartz-distributions, integral-transforms, analytic-continuation

My research has lead me to the following function that I'm trying to continue. 3 Months ago I posted [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3637584/analytic-continuation-of-phis-sum-n-ge-1-e-ns) to MSE, and have placed 3 bounties on the question, but haven't received an answer, so I've decided to ask here.

$\varphi(s)=\sum e^{-n^s}=e^{-1}+e^{-2^s}+e^{-3^s}+\cdot\cdot\cdot $

A natural question might be:

> What is the analytic continuation of $\varphi(s)?$

User @reuns noticed that $\sum_n (e^{-n^{-s}}-1)=\sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{(-1)^k}{k!} \zeta(sk).$

And an analytic continuation *is* indeed possible using the Cahen-Mellin integral to obtain the formula:

$$\varphi(s)=\Gamma\left(1+\frac1s\right)+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\zeta(-ns)$$

which is valid for $0<s<1.$

I noticed that:

$$e^{\frac{1}{\ln(x)}}=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\frac{2K_1(2\sqrt{z})}{\sqrt{z}}x^{-z}~dz$$

valid for $0<x<1$ and $\Re(z)>0$ if I'm not mistaken. Here $K_1$ is a modified Bessel function of the second kind.

Letting $x=e^{-n^{-s}}$ we obtain:

$$\varphi(s)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\frac{2K_1(2\sqrt{z})}{\sqrt{z}}\bigg(\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{zn^{-s}}\bigg)~dz$$

I think the evaluation of this will give a new formula for $\varphi(s).$ Potentially we could use the distributional version of the kernel to evaluate the integral if one exists.

> Does anyone see how to accomplish this?

Comment: Do you have a reason to believe this function odes have an analytic continuation? If so, what do you mean with "what is it"? I really doubt there is an expression for this analytic continuation in terms of more classical functions.

Comment: To lay the groundwork for this question, in what region of the complex plane does the given series already converge to an analytic function?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Re s > 0 or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: I dunno, I just thought it was an important piece of information that should be on record here.

Comment: @JohnJiang You are missing the fact that the exponents $n^s$ not only grow in size but also rotate for complex $s$, so the minus sign becomes quite useless and you get arbitrarily huge terms. I suspect that there is no continuation from the real line anywhere though I cannot offer a proof off hand.

Comment: @geocalc33 I discussed the problem with Misha Sodin and you can find the result of this discussion in the set of handwritten notes at https://drive.google.com/file/d/191PhSQzr5Q-MbfuMzmuiogJZrk2bh9Ko/view?usp=sharing .It is supposed to show that the sum of the series is *not* real analytic at any point $s>1$. I hope there is no mistake, but the argument is a bit involved. Maybe I'll post it as a proper answer later. The possibility still remains that you can go through the boundary of the half-plane $\Re z<1$ somewhere far from the real line but it is another story.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with it (though I haven't checked all the statements about fast decay carefully, I'm pretty sure that @metamorphy will supply all details if you request clarification). At least, it is in good agreement with the notes I linked to: the sum of the series is real analytic for $0<s<1$ and extends to the half-plane $\Re z<1$ but it loses the real analyticity property on the line for $s>1$, so no extension *from the real line* is possible there. My proof promptly breaks down when $s<1$, metamorphy's series promptly diverges for $s>1$, so everything seems to fit together :-)

Comment: @fedja Do you think it would be appropriate to ask a follow up question, about a possible further continuation for Re(z)<0?

Comment: Sure. If you need to know more, just state clearly what you are now interested in and link to what has been done already to give everybody a clear picture of where the things stand. Follow-ups are pretty common on this site.

Answer (score 3):

This is nowhere near a formal answer, but it might contain some useful starting points for doing computation.

The problematic aspect of the function
$$ \varphi(s) = \Gamma\left(1+\frac{1}{s}\right) + \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n!} \zeta(-ns)$$
is that $\zeta(-ns)$ grows faster than the factorial function when $s>1$, so the series cannot converge. However, the series is alternating, so from a certain viewpoint, it should 'morally' cancel out.

From a divergent series regularization point of the view, the simplest way to obtain a finite value from the function $\varphi(x)$ is truncate the series early to approximate its true value. Thus, defining
$$\varphi(s) \approx \Gamma\left(1+\frac{1}{s}\right)+ \sum_{n=0}^{N} \frac{(-1)^n}{n!} \zeta(-ns) $$
gives a good approximation to the true value of the function near $s=1$. The optimal place to truncate the series is generally at the point where the the size of the term is smallest. Here is a graph of this approximation with $N=10$ on the real line, with the infinite series shown in orange and the finite series in black
[image]

For some values of $\mathfrak{R}(s)>1$, the cancellation automatically happens on its own if we look at the integral representation rather than the sum of the residues. Thus, the integral
$$ \varphi(s) = \frac{1}{2 \pi i s} \int_{c - i N}^{c + i N} \Gamma\left(\frac{t}{s}\right) \zeta(s)dt $$
provides another way to approximate the values of $\varphi(x)$ outside of its usual realm of convergence. The two methods unsuprisingly agree with each other, but they tend to converge well in different areas.

If we want to obtain the value of $\varphi(s)$ somewhere far from $s=1$, or we want to get an arbitrarily good approximation, we can rewrite zeta using its functional equation to obtain

$$\varphi(s) = \Gamma(1+\frac{1}{s}) - \frac{1}{2} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}}{n!}\left(\frac{\left(2\pi\right)^{-ns}}{\pi}\sin\left(-\frac{\pi ns}{2}\right)\left(ns\right)!\zeta\left(1+ns\right)\right)$$
The part that causes it to diverge is the factorial, so we can replace it by its integral representation and simplify to obtain
$$\varphi(s) = \Gamma(1+\frac{1}{s}) - \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{N}e^{-t_{2}}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}}{n!}\left(\frac{t_{2}}{2\pi}\right)^{ns}\sin\left(\frac{\pi ns}{2}\right)\zeta\left(1+ns\right)dt_{2}$$

This integral agrees with the other two methods in areas where they converge. There are likely ways to simplify this last integral, though I'm not sure if such simplifications will actually make the function easier to compute.

Update: Here is a different integral that is only valid for $\mathfrak{R}(s) >1$

$$\varphi(s) = \Gamma\left(1+\frac{1}{s}\right)-\frac{1}{2} - \\ \frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-\left(\frac{t}{2\pi}\right)^{s}\cos\left(-\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)}}{e^{t}-1}\left(\sin\left(\ \left(\frac{t}{2\pi}\right)^{s}\sin\left(-\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)\right)\right) dt$$

Comment: thanks for the useful starting points. Just wanted to ask your thoughts on the integral $\varphi(s)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\frac{2K_1(2\sqrt{z})}{\sqrt{z}}\bigg(\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{zn^{-s}}\bigg)~dz$ providing a new formula

Comment: and also what do you think about continuing the function for real $s>1$ using quasi analytic continuation, since the function is smooth and in a quasi analytic class in this domain

Comment: @geocalc33 Doing some basic numerical calculations, your integral appears to agree with the ones I have presented here, which would suggest there is some sort of consistency in the value to assign the function when $\mathfrak{R}(s)>1$. I'll look more into the integral and update my answer if I discover anything

Comment: My integral agrees with $\varphi(s) = \Gamma\left(1+\frac{1}{s}\right) + \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n!} \zeta(-ns)$ on $0<s<1$?